# Torsocks not connecting

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, tor

For some reason I can't connect with torsocks via command line.
Every time I try to run something (irssi, mcabber, apt-get, whatever) it simply does not connect. I used to run terminal with tor in the past and never had a problem so far.

I run Debian 7, and this is my torsocks conf (I only paste the uncommented parts):

```
local = 127.0.0.0/255.128.0.0
local = 127.128.0.0/255.192.0.0
local = 169.254.0.0/255.255.0.0
local = 172.16.0.0/255.240.0.0
local = 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0

server = 127.0.0.1

server_port = 9050
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just in case someone has my same problem: I used the 
" LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libtorsocks.so applicationname " instead and it works fine. It is not a proper answer as it just finds an alternative solution, but if no one answers is maybe better than nothing.
Of course you can make an alias in .bashrc to make things easier, so you can just type " maytorbewithyou appname "

Comment: I have the same issue and it seems that "local =" is removed in the source and exchanged by the Phrase that the "...request might be a TCP DNS Request ..."
So it seems that further torsocks implementation wouldn't have this feature anymore ;(